# nodejs async calls, how to handle multiple requests at a url

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js, asynchronous

I was wondering how to get this done in nodejs.

I have a .get that looks like this

```
app.get('/someurl', function(req, res) {
   response = somefunc_call_to_server();
   res.send(response);
});
```

But this will be a blocking call, how to change this to handle parallel requests at /someurl?

thanks,
vik.

Comment: You need to make `somefunc_call_to_server` asynchronous. How you go about that depends on what it actual does.

Comment: Why is `somefunc_call_to_server()` blocking anyway?  And, in most cases this isn't as bad of a problem as you might think.

Comment: What is `.send()` anyway, this http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_send_message_sendhandle ?

Comment: somefunc_call_to_server() reads a bunch of stuff from the server and it can take time to return. if i make somefunc_call_to_server() async, how do i make it return the response since the method app.get would have ended (because somefunc_call_to_server is technically in a separate thread)

Comment: @dollarVar `app.get` isn't standard either. They are part of `express`.

Comment: @VikhyathReddy The method having ended doesn't matter so making it async is fine. The response to the browser doesn't get sent until you call `.send` or `.end`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Ok, found the `app` part out, got stuck on security issues.

Comment: @VikhyathReddy Pass a callback into `somefunc_call_to_server` like: `somefunc_call_to_server(function(response){ res.send(response); });`, for example. Then modify `somefunc_call_to_server`, make it asynchronous, and make it execute the callback when it is finished reading stuff from the server.

Comment: @loganfsmyth if you want to put that as an answer, i can upvote that. it was the simplest solution which worked for me. callbacks sound like a good way too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node does not expose any APIs that allow you to synchronously request data from a server. The key thing that you seem to be assuming is that a response must be sent to the server synchronously in the callback, but that is not the case. The socket open to the browser will stay connected until it either times out, or the application triggers `.end` either directly, or via Express's helper methods such as `.send`.

Generally you would accomplish your task with something like this:

```
app.get('/someurl', function(req, res, next) {
    somefunc_async_call_to_server(function(err, data){
        if (err) return next(err);

        res.send(data);
    });
});
```